# Is SRAM RED AXS Power Meter, 48/35T compatible with Tarmac Pro Disc – SRAM ETAP

Tags: power, specialized-bikes

I am interested in purchasing specialized "Tarmac Pro Disc – SRAM ETAP" bicycle that comes with "SRAM Force AXS, 48/35T" crankset.  I want a crank power meter and want to know if the "SRAM RED AXS Power Meter, 48/35T" is compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they should be compatible - the difference is in the materials/manufacturing:
[SRAM Tech Support - Difference between Force/Red AXS](https://sram.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023581694-What-are-the-main-differences-between-RED-eTap-AXS-and-Force-eTap-AXS-)

However, you can upgrade your Force AXS crankset to have power:
[SRAM Tech Support - Adding power to Force AXS crankset](https://sram.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023747893-Can-I-add-power-to-my-Force-eTap-AXS-crankset-)